# UITableViewCell tap hover

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

My tableviewcell has gray background color on selected. However, I am actually not using the "selected" feature of tableview, I just want the hover effect therefore I deselect the row right after it is selected, like this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

The problem is, the gray background only show when I tap on the cell a little more longer. If I tap on the cell real quick, I cannot see the gray color background.

Is there any way to achieve that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by either using `touchesBegan` or `touchesEnded`.
If the touch is within your tableview cell you can add a little animation.

See the `UIResponder Class` for more information:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/touchesBegan:withEvent:

Answer (score 0):

You can use this on viewDidAppear to achieve this, as soon as you redirect to your view controller this method will deselect the selected item. Hope that this will help you :-

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
}
```